# whileHover and whileTap props are not working when i apply transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, frontend, framer-motion

I am animating an icon using framer motion and while over and whileTap props are not working when I apply the transition.

Here is the code

```
 <motion.div
                  animate={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                  initial={{ x: -100, y: -100, opacity: 0.6 }}
                  whileHover={{ scale: 1.5, opacity: 1 }}
                  drag={true}
                  transition={{ delay : 2 }}
                  whileTap={{ scale: 0.8, opacity: 1 }}
                  key={genre.id}
                  className=" cursor-pointer mx-6 my-10 text-2xl text-white list-none"
                >
                  <Icon key={key} />
</motion.div>
```

When I remove this

```
transition={{delay : 2}}
```

then hover and tap options work properly.

But I need to delay the original animation and hover property too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably *are* still working, but only after the 2 second delay.

You can move the transition with delay into the `animate` prop. Then it will only apply to the initial animation, not the hover or tap transitions.

Like this:

```
<motion.div
    animate={{ x: 0, y: 0, transition: { delay: 2 } }} // put delay here
    initial={{ x: -100, y: -100, opacity: 0.6 }}
    whileHover={{ scale: 1.5, opacity: 1 }}
    drag={true}
    // no delay on the main component
    whileTap={{ scale: 0.8, opacity: 1 }}
    key={genre.id}
    className=" cursor-pointer mx-6 my-10 text-2xl text-white list-none"
    >
        <Icon key={key} />
</motion.div>
```